# How should I amend my base case to avoid stack overflow in my recursive code?

Tags: java, recursion, methods, stack-overflow

Basically my code needs to calculate the sum of the path in an nxn matrix ( starts at 0,0), and adds up the smallest sum where I'm only allowed to move right or downwards.

For example the matrix below should output 18 because the min path is 5 1 2 4 6, but I don't know how should my base case be here. I know I should stop the recursion once I reach array [n][n] though..in my code below I'm getting a stackoverflow error.

> ```
> 512
> 234
> 566
> ```

```
import java.util.*;

public class shortestpath {

    public static int findminpath(int [][]c,int x,int y,int n) {
        if (x==n-1 && y==n-1) {
            return c[x][y];
        } else {
            int path1 = findminpath(c,x+1,y,n);
            int path2 = findminpath (c,x,y+1,n);
            return c[x][y] + Math.min(path1,path2);
        }
    }

    public static void main (String [] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner (System.in);
        int[][] array = new int[3][3];
        for (int i=0; i<array.length; i++){
            for (int j=0; j<array.length; j++){
                array[i][j] = sc.nextInt();
            }
        }
        System.out.println(findminpath(array,0,0,array.length));
    }
}
```

Comment: Indentation might seem like a superficial concern, but it's often the key to understanding someone's code. This is totally out of control here, there's no organization at all. If you can clean this up you might be one step closer to understanding what's wrong.

Comment: @tadman is it better now ?

Comment: That looks way more readable. Nice work.

Answer (score 0):

The issue comes from your if statement.

```
if (x==n-1 && y==n-1)
```

Note that if you trace through your code by hand, you will have the following method calls on your stack.

```
findminpath(array, 0, 0, 3)
findminpath(array, 1, 0, 3)
findminpath(array, 2, 0, 3)
findminpath(array, 3, 0, 3)
findminpath(array, 4, 0, 3)
findminpath(array, 5, 0, 3)
findminpath(array, 6, 0, 3)
findminpath(array, 7, 0, 3)
....
```

The reason is because of the `&&` you have in the if statement. y hasn't incremented yet, and it will never increment from this recursion because you will go until x reaches the maximum int value.

Comment: *until it reaches max int ... 

Comment: Eh. Fair enough. You win.

Comment: @SaxyPandaBear Can you give me a hint for the base case? because i have tried using || insteaf of && but then this wont reach the max int , and i tried using c [x][y]==c[n-1][n-1] but still its not working

Comment: It seems like you just really have to go and rethink your approach. Think about what you need to keep in mind. What are the bounds for your recursion? You know that if x is equal to the length of your n by n matrix, you can't keep incrementing x, and you know that if y is equal to the length of your n by n matrix you can't keep incrementing y. 

Why are you putting it all into 1 case? Isn't incrementing x a different path than incrementing y? Don't they have different requirements to terminate?